# Include .npmrc while creating a new angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface

I am creating a command line application using node.js. The application wraps the `ng new` command from angular CLI. While creating a new angular project, dependencies are installed automatically.

The problem here is we are using a private npmjs repository which at times may not have some specified dependencies in it. To avoid this situation, I thought to have a .npmrc file in which I can define to fetch the organization specific node modules from the private repository and rest of the node modules from the npm repository.

Is there any way, using which I can add a .npmrc file during angular project creation with the command ng new?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so you are wanting to hijack the ng new command to add your custom scaffolding? e.g. such as a .npmrc file

Comment: @MichaelMano, Yes, kind of. Just like vue has a plugin and preset kind of thing where you can have a custom template to create your project. I wanna do the same with angular

Comment: my best guess to solve this it's schematics

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to avoid using global config:

1. Make a project directory
2. Add a .yarnrc file to your project directory with your desired registry like:
   registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
3. Then `yarn init` in the directory
4. Then `yarn add ng` so it adds ng from the repository you listed
5. Continue with `ng new ${yourprojectname}` to use the local ng you just created
6. After ng new creates the angular directory, you may want to also copy the .npmrc and .yarnrc inside the project and configure them with your desired registry and run `npm install` just to be sure.